# Merge anonymous account to email and password account in firebase with polymer

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication

I am creating a web app with polymer and firebase, and I want be able to merge anonymously logged in accounts to be able to merge to an email and password account.

I found the official documentation on how to achieve this
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth
, but when I try it out, it does not work.

Documentation provides the code sample

```
auth.currentUser.link(credential).then(function(user) {
  console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
});
```

I am confused at this point since this "auth" variable popped out of no where.

I have tried substituting the user property of my element

```
<firebase-auth 
  id="auth"
  user="{{user}}"
  on-error="handleError">
</firebase-auth>
```

, but it gave me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.user.link is not a function
```

What variable am I supposed to have for the "auth" in this example? Or, how can I merge anonymous account to an email and password account using polymerfire?

Comment: There is an example on this part of the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account 

Basically:
1. Get the credencials for the provider
2. Link Accounts 
3. Continue the auth flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

Turns out that the "link" method is deprecated and instead, we have to use "linkWithCredential", so the code would be

```
this.$.auth.auth.currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential).then(function(user) {
  console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Polymer's firebase-auth element has an auth property. So you could bind to it:

```
<firebase-auth 
  id="auth"
  user="{{user}}"
  auth="{{auth}}"
  on-error="handleError">
</firebase-auth>
```

& then use this.auth directly in your containing element or you could just reference it directly in your code w/out binding like:

```
this.$.auth.auth
```

Side note - makes it kind of confusing that the docs for firebase-auth give an example element id of "auth" leading to the "auth.auth" above.

Comment: I actually tried this, but got the following error

    " this.$.auth.auth.currentUser.link is not a function"

Comment: Thanks though, "this.$.auth.auth" helped